# Spark & Scala - NullPointerException in RDD traversal

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a number of CSV files and need to combine them into a RDD by part of their filenames.

For example, for the below files

```
$ ls   
20140101_1.csv  20140101_3.csv  20140201_2.csv  20140301_1.csv 
20140301_3.csv 20140101_2.csv  20140201_1.csv  20140201_3.csv
```

I need to combine files with names `20140101*.csv` into a RDD to work on it and so on.

I am using `sc.wholeTextFiles` to read the entire directory and then grouping the filenames by their patters to form a string of filenames.
I am then passing the string to sc.textFile to open the files as a single RDD.

This is the code I have -

```
val files = sc.wholeTextFiles("*.csv")
val indexed_files = files.map(a => (a._1.split("_")(0),a._1))
val data = indexed_files.groupByKey

data.map { a =>
  var name = a._2.mkString(",")
  (a._1, name)
}

data.foreach { a =>
  var file = sc.textFile(a._2)
  println(file.count)
}
```

And I get `SparkException - NullPointerException` when I try to call `textFile`. The error stack refers to an Iterator inside the RDD. I am not able to understand the error -

```
15/07/21 15:37:37 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 65.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 65.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 65.0 (TID 115, 10.132.8.10): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:33)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:32)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:870)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:870)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1765)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1765)
```

However, when I do `sc.textFile(data.first._2).count` in the spark shell, I am able to form the RDD and able to retrieve the count.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "  var file = sc.textFile(a._2)" inside the foreach of another rdd map isn't going to work. You can't nest RDDs like that.

Comment: Thank you @Paul... I corrected it and I am able to create the RDD now. Please answer the question and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a comment to an answer:

```
var file = sc.textFile(a._2)
```

inside the `foreach` of another RDD isn't going to work. You can't nest RDDs like that.